# Allocate percentage of tokens to the wallet who deployed the liquidity and DEX

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I'm new to solidity and I have to developed a ERC-20 Token. The functionality of token is almost done but in the mint function I want to cut 2% of the tokens user buy and send 1 % to liquidity pool and 1% to the owner who deployed the liquidity pool. How can I achieve this functionality ?

```
     function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) public onlyOwner {
     balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
     totalSupply += mintedAmount;
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(mintedAmount);
    emit Transfer(owner, target, mintedAmount);                                               
}
```

Comment: John, Could you answer this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72125229/how-to-set-the-1-of-fees-for-liquidity-pool-1-for-all-accounts-2charity-wal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise inheriting Open Zeppelin's ERC20 contract when implementing your own token. See https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/erc20 and https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

For minting new tokens you want to use the internal`_mint(target, amount)`, which mints an `amount` of tokens that are owned by `target`.

To do what you want, you would need to calculate the amount of tokens that should be minted to each account and then mint them to each account.

```
function buyTokens(uint256 amount) external {
  _mint(msg.sender, (98 * amount)/100);
  _mint(liquidityPoolOwnerAddress, amount/100);
  _mint(liquidityPoolAddress, amount/100);
}
```